# using entities as json objects in EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.0

I have below model structure

```
public class A621
{
    public Guid? AirflowSource { get; set; }
    public string AirflowSourceName { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class A170 
{
    public Guid? AirflowSource { get; set; }
    public string AirflowSourceName { get; set; }
}
```

I am using above models in entities like as below

```
public class MechanicalData
{
    public List<A621> A621 { get; private set; }
    public List<A170> A170 { get; private set; }
    public List<Lab> Lab { get; private set; }
}

public class MechanicalTypeData
{
    public MechanicalData MechanicalData { get; set; }
}

public class SpaceType : IAEIMaster, IRevisionData
{
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public MechanicalTypeData MechanicalTypeData { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

you can see that i am using this entity `MechanicalTypeData` in `spacetype` entity as json column and these entities `A621` and `A170` are child entities of `MechanicalData` ..

Now i would like to use `A621` and `A170` as a individual lookup tables and these are going to be really existing in DB. I am using EF core code first approach while creating tables.

my question is can i use `A621` and `A170` for both purposes, by both I mean as individual lookup tables and adding child objects to json that is going to be sit in column as json object.

Could any one throw some light on this or any other better approach as well. 
many thanks in advance

Comment: please let me know if you need more information on this

Comment: `adding child objects to json that is going to be sit in column as json object for SpaceType` - So you want a string that saves into 1 table.column as json format with those properties?

Comment: yeah, if you see `spacetype` entity i am using `MechanicalTypeData ` as json column with the data used from `MechanicalData ` and this entity is internally connected to `A170` and `A621`

Comment: you could instead have a string Property instead in SpaceType, then serialize your A170 or A621 objects -> string with Newtonsoft and save that to your data column.

Comment: You can use EF Core Value Conversions to store a collection in a JSON column. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Comment: @LinkedListT, i am using postgreSQL and when i am using like i mentioned data is going to be stored as json with out writing code for conversion explicitly.. I just wanna check the we can use entities in both way

Comment: Could any one please suggest any idea on this..